# System Document describing what the system does

Tags: documentation, terminology

We have a bunch of requirements documents and class diagrams, but are missing the document that brings it all together.

What is the correct term for a document that gives an overview of what a system does? Or what is the best way to present an overall picture of what is going on.

Something that starts with a high level picture of what’s going on, describes what the system provides, who it interacts with, and  any dependencies, etc ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a word request, which belongs on English Language & Usage, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back in the 2167A and MIL-498 days we called it a [Software Product Specification](http://homepage.mac.com/simon.j.wright/pushface.org/mil_498/sps-did.htm#scope) (or SPS).

If that isn't quite what you are looking for, try surfing around [Simon's MIL-498 document website](http://homepage.mac.com/simon.j.wright/pushface.org/mil_498/fig17.htm) and see if one looks like what you need. You (probably) don't have to follow any of them exactly, but they make good templates.

Comment: Maybe software design description  http://homepage.mac.com/simon.j.wright/pushface.org/mil_498/sdd-did.htm#scope

Answer (score 0):

What about a nice Domain model?

Comment: That sounds too much like a description of an object representation of  our system.

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself: System Overview.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an architecture document to me. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture